# Why there is a runtime.morestack in make([]int, 14) but not in make([]int, 13)?

Tags: go, runtime, goroutine

I've already known that the `runtime.morestack` will cause goroutine context switch (If the sysmon goroutine has marked it "has to switch").

And when I do some experiment around this, I've found an interesting fact.

Compare the following codes.

```
func main() {
    _ = make([]int, 13)
}
```

---

```
func main() {
    _ = make([]int, 14)
}
```

And compile them by running the following command: (Tried in go1.9 and go 1.11)

```
$ go build -gcflags "-S -l -N" x.go
```

You may find a major difference that the first outputs contains `CALL   runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)` while the second doesn't.

I guess it is an optimization, but why?

Comment: This series may be enlightening https://blog.altoros.com/golang-internals-part-5-runtime-bootstrap-process.html

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for the link! It really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I got the answer.

- Making a slice that less than 65,536 bytes and not escaped from the func will be allocated in the stack, not the heap.
- StackGuard0 will be higher than the stack's lowest address by at least 128 bytes. (Even after downsizing)
- make([]int, 13) will allocate 128 bytes memories in total.

> sizeof(struct slice) + 13 * 8 = 24 + 104 = 128.

So the answer is clear, this is an optimization for `amd64`.

For a leaf function, if it used less than 128 bytes memories, the compiler wouldn't generate codes that checking if the stack is overflowed (because there are enough spaces).

Here is the explanation in `go/src/runtime/stack.go`

> The per-goroutine g->stackguard is set to point StackGuard bytes
>   above the bottom of the stack.  Each function compares its stack
>   pointer against g->stackguard to check for overflow.  To cut one
>   instruction from the check sequence for functions with tiny frames,
>   the stack is allowed to protrude StackSmall bytes below the stack
>   guard.  Functions with large frames don't bother with the check and
>   always call morestack.  The sequences are (for amd64, others are
>   similar):